# infinite scroll does not work when width of a page is less then 981px

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

When page width is more then 980px, infinite scroll works fine, but when it is less then 981px it just stops working.

I tough this is connected only with height but it looks like I'm wrong.

**Code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

    console.log("infinite scroll works");


}
```

});

Is there a way around this for devices with width less then 981px ?

Here is reference to full project: https://github.com/strix25/1-million-books-generator-and-infinite-scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution to this problem.

**Code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() + 1 >= $('body').height() - $(window).height()) {
  console.log("infinite scroll works"); 
 }
```

});